# detect first app launch in windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10-mobile

I am new to windows 10 application development. I want to show some details to user when only user launch the app for the first time. Please help me to solve this problem !!

Comment: What is your problem at the first place?

Comment: Registry, Application-Settings, after all you could even create a "marker" file and check existence (not recommended) ... did you do any research?

Comment: I just want to create some pages which include information about the app. I tried with IsolatedStorageSettings . but it doesn't exist in windows 10.

Comment: So which part is the actual problem? Getting together the info, or only showing them at first start?

Comment: I just want to only showing them at first start

Comment: You can simply store your texts in a file installed with your application. When you start the app, check if the file exists and show its content, then delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ApplicationDataContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdatacontainer) and check for a boolean on startup.

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
if (localSettings.Values["HasStartedOnce"] == null) { 
    // (...do first-time-only things)
    localSettings.Values["HasStartedOnce"] = true;
}
```